# How to resize image of earth to be flat in Python for Leaflet?

Tags: python, leaflet, spatial, arcgis, gdal

I got two images of earth from NASA, both 2400x2400px in size that I've processed to be heatmaps and finally combined into one image of size 4800x2400px. This image will be used as an overlay in a web application using Leaflet and OpenStreetMap. Previously I would use Arcgis to manually open hdf5 files, extract the images I needed, alter their colors and combine them etc. The last step in Arcgis would then be to use the inbuild coordinates system to 'flatten' the images, as this is required by Leaflet. The original images are pictures of a sphree (earth), which doesn't work well with Leaflet, so that is why this step is required.

Now I would like to do this from code as well, to achieve a fully-automatic system that converts hdf5 files to png files ready for Leaflet. In the case of the forementioned 4800x2400px image, Arcgis would convert it to a new image of size 3624x3180px. If I would simply resize my 4800x2400px in Python using the PIL library the result would not be the same, so Arcgis is doing some sort of manipulation to properly flatten the image so it still matches the earths surface or at least very close to it. When I say it is not the same, this is very apparent when putting the 2 images (one from code, one from Arcgis) onto an overlay in Leaflet as the image generated from code is swifted and not ontop of the intended coordinates.

Is there any way to flatten my png image in Python so it is as close to reality as it gets?
I hope my question and explanation makes any sense ..
I don't have much code to show, and the processing I'm doing is simply a manipulation of the color code for each pixel and nothing more. My end result is a PIL Image, that I would love to resize/flatten.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I've come across the rasterio library for Python, that uses GDAL and even offers reprojection of arrays to new coordinate reference systems. However I'm unsure on how to actually use it since it requires a destination parameter and I have to specify the size of the ndarray and I don't know the size of that obviously.. 
Does anyone know how to use this?
https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.warp.html#rasterio.warp.reproject
I have information about my original image such as the 'Projection=HE5_GCTP_GEO' and 'GridOrigin=HE5_HDFE_GD_UL'.

Comment: You may have more luck asking this question on GIS Stack Exchange, as your issue is really specific about geographic projection.

Comment: I have tried posting it on the GIS Stack Exchange as well, thanks.